# Entity Framework 6, Database First. Update Model not working correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My EF6 code does not reflect changes in my database, and has discrepencies within the EF6 code itself.

The class code Has the `UserId` property at the bottom - just under the Highlighted `LoggedOnUserName` property. This is correct.

[image: This is the Class]

However, in Visual Studio when expanding the Model.tt I see this:

[image: Model.tt]

As you can see the model stops at the `LoggedInUserName` property and does not include the `UserId` property.

Finally with the source code itself I can not access the `Client` class at all.

[image]

Sorry for all the images but it is the best I can do with the current Dev Machine.

**The Question:** How can I get the EF6 generated code to correctly reflect the Database? I have clicked on the designer model and updated but to no effect.

Comment: Try right click on Model.tt and select Run Custom Tool. It might solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is the solution I found.

I tried using edmgen.exe which comes with EF. I opened a cmd.exe window in the solution and ran edmgen. which is a little difficult. the most awkward setting is actually the connection string to use. You can get that from web or app.cfg.

It unfortunately did not work.

What did work was to right click on the Models.edmx entry in the Solution Explorer and deleting it and then Add New Item -> Data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model

This recreated the who thing from scratch which fixed all the problems.